# AWS SAM Template Create API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using the following SAM template for a lambda function

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  GetFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: handler.get
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Environment:
        Variables: 
          S3_BUCKET: bucket
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /resource/{resourceId}
            Method: get
```

I'm a bit confused on the Events section.  When I deploy this, the lambda function gets created fine, however since I am mentioning Api under events I expected it to create an API Gateway.  However when I navigate into the API Gateway section https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/  I do not see any API Gateway created.  When I navigate into the CloudFormation stacks and have a look at the template it shows the API Gateway, however it does not show one being created.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Double check and look at the resource tab for the particular stack.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there are no issues in SAM template. Have you had a look at the Resources section in stack detail? There should be a resource of type **AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi** along with a physical id and a status. You could also try deleting the stack and redeploying it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a SAM Template Lambda function if you don't specify any restapi ID then it will create a restapi on its own but if you need extra things like cors and request template alike feature you can create a api gateway object and then use the !Ref in your event of the lambda function declaration so probably you are missing something try to hit the url defined in the declaration.